# Issues with creating an .ipa and dysm for ad-hoc distribution in XCode 4

Tags: xcode4, ipa

I am trying to create a .ipa file for ad-hoc distribution in XCode 4, which I am sucessfully able to do. I followed [this article](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4).

The problem is: how do I create a dysm file as well?

Answer (score 0):

The dsym file is saved in your "release" build folder. Check that folder out, the file is in there.

You have to make sure you set the [*Generate Debug Symbols* to *YES* in your Project Build Settings.](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/symbolizingcrashdumps.html)

I detailed the steps to combine that with a [crash file made on that release on my site](http://dominic-tancredi.com/category/code-hacking/iphone-objective-c/).

Comment: Dominic, when i create a archive by going to Product menu of xcode i don't even see Release folder inside this location ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Doot-exgfzixoirsvxpdakvdfunnjugva/Build/Products where do I find the release folder

Comment: I have set the Generate Debug Symbols to YES in my project target build setting as well as in the project build settings

Comment: I'm confused. Where is your project located on your hard drive? There should be a release or a build folder there that contains your .app. Next to it is the .dsym file. In XCode, just right click on the target and select "Show in Finder"

Comment: I guess you are talking about Xcode 3, I am working on Xcode 4

Comment: Go into Builder, select your app in the Target, right-click : "Reveal in Finder" and it will take you to the proper folder

Comment: I just did it for XCode 4. In the same folder as your app, there exists the app.dSYM file. i.e. in "/Users/dominictancredi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-blvuufdgzcpwbtbshgphuwnjkhuy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos"

Comment: Hi Dominic, I guess there is some confusion here, so I am not building the app, but I am directly going to Product->Archive using the Ad-hoc profile for it and then i get a .ipa file. But /Volumes/Personal/Yogesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Doot-exgfzixoirsvxpdakvdfunnjugva/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos doesn't have anything because I don't have my phone connected i do have /Volumes/Personal/Yogesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Doot-exgfzixoirsvxpdakvdfunnjugva/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator folder which gets populated with my .app file and .dysm file when i run app 1/2

Comment: on debug mode, but when i generate archive debug-iphonesimultor doesn't have a new .app and .dysm file, are you suggesting that first i run it on the debug and then take the .dysm file from debug-iphonesimulator and then without making any code changes make an archive

Comment: In short: yes, you need a .dysm file from your build so that you can read crash reports.